# A tournament on $k2^k$ vertices always contains a dominating set of size $k$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method, extremal-graph-theory

This is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765543/why-doesn-t-this-work-proof-for-the-lower-bound-of-the-size-sigmak-of-the). Please see the definitions and proof attempt 2.

I discovered that a similar argument was used to prove the statement for the tournaments of size $2^k$ (as in, for example, [this document](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Emegiddo/pdf/uzx.pdf), Fact 2.5.). I can’t seem to improve the bound further, and would need some help.

Comment: Are you sure you interpreted $\Omega$ correctly?

Comment: I understood $\sigma (k) = \Omega (k2^k)$ as: there’s a constant $c > 0$, such that any tournament with at least $ck2^k$ vertices has the property $S_k$, i.e. its smallest dominating set has size greater than $k$. Is this correct and equivalent to what I’m trying to show?

Comment: So why must it be $c=1$ but not, say $c>10^{10^{10}}$?

Comment: I see. So I actually have to show that, any tournament of less than $ck2^k$ vertices (but not just $k2^k$) would have a dominating set of size $k$?